# MySQL SELECT and order as associative array

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

First of all thanks for viewing, I am having a mysql question which I have honestly no idea how to tackle. If someone could help me out I'd really appreciate it.

I have the following two tables in my mysql database (see link below)
http://www.rodneywormsbecher.com/sql-tables.jpg

The output I'd like to achieve is as below:

```
array (
    [0] => category_name
        [total_userhours] => count(id) userhours
    [1] => category_name
        [total_userhours] => count(id) userhours
    [2] => category_name
        [total_userhours] => count(id) userhours
)
```

So the first result in the array has the category name and under it, it makes a variable that counts all userhours that have the userhour_category_id.

Thanks in advance,
Rodney

/ edit I got 2 working solutions from the replies:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($Database->customQuery("SELECT * FROM userhour") as $r) {
    $cat_id             =   $r['userhour_category_id'];
    $cat_result_set     =   $Database->fetchSingleArray($Database->customQuery("SELECT * FROM userhour_category WHERE id={$cat_id}"));
    $cat_name           =   $cat_result_set['category_name'];
    $count              =   $Database->fetchSingleArray($Database->customQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM userhour WHERE userhour_category_id={$cat_id}"));
    $data[$cat_name]    =   $count['total'];
}
print_r($data);




$Sql1 = "SELECT c.category_name, count(*) AS total_userhours
          FROM `userhour` u
          JOIN `userhour_category` c
          ON (u.userhour_category_id = c.id)
          GROUP BY u.userhour_category_id";


$test = $Database->fetchAllArray($Database->customQuery($Sql1));
print_r($test);
```

both work like a Charm, but i prefer the sql way of doing it.

output:

```
 Array
(
    [Graphic design] => 15
    [Web design] => 9
    [Newsletter] => 1
)


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Web design
            [total_userhours] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Graphic design
            [total_userhours] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Newsletter
            [total_userhours] => 1
        )

)
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: First person I know of that updated the question with the solutions output haha, nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group you `userhour` by category and then count each group:

```
SELECT c.category_name, count(*) AS total_userhours
FROM `userhour` u 
    JOIN `userhour_category` c 
        ON (u.userhour_category_id = c.id)
GROUP BY u.userhour_category_id
```

I didn't test the query, but it should work.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for answering my question and opening my eyes on how to make complex queries in MySql.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","name");
$data = array();
foreach($db->query("select * from userhour") as $r):
    $cat = $r['project_name'];
    $data[$cat] = array(
                   'id' => $r['id'],
                   'mins' => $r['minutes_spend']
                  );
endforeach;
$db->close();
```

And change the columns to what you need, but you should get a similar output to what you're expecting.

(I cannot see your table names and/or reference to the userhour things so just edit it as you need).

Comment: Not a problem, switch things around as you need. You can also `foreach` the `$data` to use it effectively. ie: `foreach($data as $k=>$v): echo 'Project name: '.$k.'\n Id: '.$v['id']; //ect...`